# Bash unexpected token near 'then'

Tags: bash

I have a syntax error, more like a unexpected symbol near a token 'then', but I can't figure it out..

```
    #!/bin/bash

function Functie(){
LINE=1
while read -r CURRENT_LINE; do
   CONTOR=1
for word in "$CURRENT_LINE"; do
   if[ "$word" == "$2" ];
then
   CONTOR=$CONTOR+1
fi
done
if [ "$CONTOR" -eq "$3" ];
then
   echo "$CURRENT_LINE"
fi
LINE=$LINE+1
done < "./"$1""
}

Functie "File1.txt" "Ana" "2"
```

Comment: Give a space between if and square bracket.

Comment: ah, didn't observe that, It helped my problem, thanks and sorry for putting a dumb question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run your code through [ShellCheck](https://shellcheck.net) to catch several syntax errors.

[image: ShellCheck Output]

Correcting them yields:

```
#!/bin/bash

function Functie(){
LINE=1
while read -r CURRENT_LINE; do
   CONTOR=1
for word in $CURRENT_LINE; do
   if [ "$word" == "$2" ];
then
   CONTOR=$CONTOR+1
fi
done
if [ "$CONTOR" -eq "$3" ];
then
   echo "$CURRENT_LINE"
fi
LINE=$LINE+1
done < ./"$1"
}

Functie "File1.txt" "Ana" "2"
```

One issue it doesn't detect is the bad assignments. To increment a variable write one of these:

```
CONTOR=$(($CONTOR+1))
CONTOR=$((CONTOR+1))
((CONTOR += 1))
((++CONTOR))
```

Comment: Ugh, don't even mention `let`.

Comment: @chepner I can replace it with `$[...]`?